# Array y objetos sacar valores y hacer un objeto nuevo javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Necesito tomar el valor de del elemento tanto `answer` como value y crear un nuevo objeto con los valores 
 **EJEMPLO:**

```
   array=[
     { answer:"answer_1",value:"respuesta 1"}
     { answer:"answer_2",value:"respuesta 2"}
     { answer:"answer_3",value:"respuesta 3"}
    ]
```

**Resultado**

```
obj={
 answer_1:"respuesta 1",
 answer_2:"respuesta 2",
 answer_3:"respuesta 3"
}
```

Comment: ¿Nos muestras por favor lo que has intentado?

Comment: Usa el método [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

Comment: digamos que ya yo creo el array con los objetos pero no se como hacer para hacer el ese resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede usar `.reduce()` para hacer un objeto partiendo de un array. Para usar valores como claves de otro objeto es útil usar la sintaxis `objeto1[objeto2.clave] =`.

```js
const array = [
    { answer: "answer_1", value: "respuesta 1" },
    { answer: "answer_2", value: "respuesta 2" },
    { answer: "answer_3", value: "respuesta 3" }
];

const res = array.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c.answer] = c.value;
    return p;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```